# Georeferenced Köppen climate classification maps

Tags: geospatial, climate

Wikimedia Commons has a large collection of Köppen climate classification maps in its [Category:Köppen-Geiger](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:K%C3%B6ppen-Geiger).  For example, [Russia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Russia_K%C3%B6ppen.svg), [Canada](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Canada_K%C3%B6ppen.svg), or [USA](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:USA_map_of_K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification.svg).  The formats available on Wikimedia Commons are (mostly) PNG and SVG, which are not georeferenced.  Is there any public source of Köppen climate classification maps in georeferenced formats, such as geotiff, so that I can load it into GIS software and combine it with other maps?

This would make it much easier to tell, for example, [what part of British Columbia has BSk](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:British_Columbia_K%C3%B6ppen.svg).

Comment: Seems like [the supplement here](https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/11/1633/2007/hess-11-1633-2007.html) might contain it, need to have a closer look.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247403/55095) gis.stackexchange.com answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a set of global 1‑km resolution Köppen-Geiger climate classification maps for the present day (1980–2016) and for projected future conditions (2071–2100) under climate change.

Citation: Beck, H.E., N.E. Zim­mer­mann, T.R. McVicar, N. Ver­gopolan, A. Berg, E.F. Wood: Present and future Köp­pen-Geiger cli­mate clas­si­fi­ca­tion maps at 1‑km res­o­lu­tion, Sci­en­tif­ic Data 5:180214, doi:[10.1038/sdata.2018.214](https://doi.org/10.1038/sdata.2018.214) (2018).

Web site: http://www.gloh2o.org/koppen/

Data download (GeoTIFF + legend): 
https://figshare.com/articles/Present_and_future_K_ppen-Geiger_climate_classification_maps_at_1-km_resolution/6396959/2